# How to get hidden layer/state outputs from a Bert model?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Based on the documentation provided here, https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.21.3/src/transformers/modeling_outputs.py#L101, how can i read all the outputs, last_hidden_state (), pooler_output and hidden_state. in my sample code below, i get the outputs

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig

config = BertConfig.from_pretrained("xxx", output_hidden_states=True)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("xxx", config=config)

outputs = model(inputs)
```

when i print one of the output (sample below) . i looked through the documentation to see if i can use some functions of this class to just get the last_hidden_state values , but i'm not sure of the type here.

the value for the last_hidden_state =

```
tensor([[...
```

is it some class or tuple or array .
how can i get the values or array of values such as

```
[0, 1, 2, 3 , ...]
```

```
BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndNoAttention(
last_hidden_state=tensor([
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 
         11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
         18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
         15, 16, 17,
         18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
        ...
        hidden_states= ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions` you retrieve is class that inherits from OrderedDict ([code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/90f6fe9155d2f477588d9ba2d7c697a1933e205a/src/transformers/utils/generic.py#L148)) that holds [pytorch tensors](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html). You can access the keys of the `OrderedDict` like properties of a class and, in case you do not want to work with Tensors, you can them to python lists or numpy. Please have a look at the example below:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

t = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
m = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

i = t("This is a test", return_tensors="pt")
o = m(**i, output_hidden_states=True)

print(o.keys())
print(type(o.last_hidden_state))
print(o.last_hidden_state.tolist())
print(o.last_hidden_state.detach().numpy())
```

Output:

```
odict_keys(['last_hidden_state', 'pooler_output', 'hidden_states'])
<class 'transformers.modeling_outputs.BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions'>
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
[[[0.36328405141830444, 0.018902940675616264, 0.1893523931503296, ..., 0.09052444249391556, 1.4617693424224854, 0.0774402841925621]]]
[[[ 0.36328405  0.01890294  0.1893524  ... -0.0259465   0.38701165
    0.19099694]
  [ 0.30656984 -0.25377586  0.76075834 ...  0.2055152   0.29494798
    0.4561815 ]
  [ 0.32563183  0.02308523  0.665546   ...  0.34597045 -0.0644953
    0.5391255 ]
  [ 0.3346715  -0.02526359  0.12209094 ...  0.50101244  0.36993945
    0.3237842 ]
  [ 0.18683438  0.03102166  0.25582778 ...  0.5166369  -0.1238729
    0.4419385 ]
  [ 0.81130844  0.4746894  -0.03862225 ...  0.09052444  1.4617693
    0.07744028]]]
```